# LiDAR Velodyne Veloview PointCloud Data

Tags: mapping, pcap, point-clouds, lidar

I'm new to this .. I am working on some mapping project and I need help filtering LIDAR pointcloud data. I have two questions and i hope you can help in this: 
    1) Can you use Veloview to filter Point Cloud data?  Can you crop the data captured? if so, what's the process?
    2) Can you export/convert PCAP file in .csv?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [VeloView User Guide](https://github.com/Kitware/VeloView/blob/master/Documentation/VeloView_User_Guide.pdf)

For manipulation and analysis purpose, you can use Veloview-python console interface mentioned in section **III - Python Console**.

For cropping the captured data:
 File --> Save As --> [preferred option] --> Frames from.

Comment: Hey Ammad, thank you for this information! I actually looked into veloview but i want to automate it this with other sensors! do you think i can do this and setup veloview to only capture the data thru the filter i'm building? I want to push this data to ROS to fuse it with other sensors!

Comment: Can you give a little more detail about the filter you are trying to built? And you are using veloview to capture the packets or just to view/load the data(.pcap file)?